# Why is this function returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created a javascript function that calls on a php page to return either a 1 or a 0.  The return is always coming back as undefined.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      if($('#username').val()!=""){
        alert(checkfees($('#username').val())); //returns undefined
        if(checkfees($('#username').val())){
          alert("has fees");
        }
        else{
          alert("no fees");
        }
      }
    });

    function checkfees(username){
      $.post( "checkfees.php", { uname: username }).done(function(data) {
        if(data=="1"){
          return true;
        }
        else{
          return false;
        }
      });
    }
```

The function appears to work.  The variable "data" has the correct information (either a 1 or 0), so the correct if statement is hit inside the checkfees function, but the return keeps coming back as undefined.

Comment: blame the "A" in "AJAX."

Comment: Think about what functions the `return`s are actually in.

Comment: you are missing a return statement before `$.post`. Note that this will return a promise. Further reading in the duplicate link

Comment: I thought that was what the 'done' part of the call was for.  it waited until after the call finished. So i should save data as a variable and call the return outside of the post method?

Comment: by the way, `if(data=="1"){ return true; } else{ return false; }` is exactly the same thing as `return data=="1"`

Comment: `if(checkfees($('#username').val())){` this can't work due to the async behaviour of promises. Your `.done` **will be executed** but the result will never be read due to the missing return statement

Comment: Thanks, all.  Got it.